# Migrate email from generic IMAP server to Google Apps without SSL

Tags: email, ssl, import, google-apps

We have to migrate a lot of email from an IMAP server to Gmail in Google Apps. Google Apps have a migration tool, but it works **only** with a server with a [valid SSL certificate](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/Gmail-SSL-POP3-Certificate-Self-Signed,news-16468.html).

We wouldn't want to do a manual import... someone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [GAMME](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/exchangemigration). It should do SSL w/o a valid cert.